# Run multiple servers in Netty without closeFuture().sync()

Tags: java, netty

I'm working on a Netty application. I want to run multiple servers on different ports and that is not working without the (blocking) `closeFuture().sync()`.

I start the servers in my `ServerManager` class using the following code:

```
gpcmServer = new GpcmServer(port);

gpspServer = new GpspServer(port);
```

In those classes, I start the server as follows:

```
public GpspServer(int port) throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            // Add the server handler and its decoder
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new GpspDecoder(), new GpspServerHandler());
                        }
                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            bindFuture = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();

            bindFuture.channel().closeFuture();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
```

However, I can't connect to the server when I don't call `closeFuture().sync()`. When I add `.sync()` to `bindFuture.channel().closeFuture()`, I can connect to the server. How can I keep doing it this way and still make the server work?

Comment: You should use two separate threads to start the servers, one for each server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `EventLoopGroup.shutdown*()` method, the event loop will close all sockets and server sockets it is managing before terminating itself.  Therefore, if you did not wait until the server socket is closed, your `finally` block will terminate your server completely.

What you actually need to do to run multiple servers is:

- bind multiple times,
- do *NOT* call `shutdownGracefully()` until you want to shut your server down.

Comment: Thanks, I totally overlooked the finally part!